# Use the same header,footer,panel in all jQuery Mobile pages

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins

iam using jquery mobile & phonegap to make Html App .
there is any method to make the header,footer and panel are same in all pages Without the need to add the code every time in all pages ?
there is any simple template to do that ?

Comment: Use external Panel and Toolbars.

Comment: could you give me an example please ?

Comment: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/panel-external/  and http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/toolbar-fixed-persistent/

Comment: http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/panel-external/ http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/toolbar-external/

Comment: @Omar, beat you by 1 second ;-)